# How to add readable text to URL with NodeJS Express?

Tags: node.js, express, url, routes, url-rewriting

I have links that looks like this on my website:

`https://website.com/view?id=8d23iva`

When users go to the link, I want the URL to change based on information related the `id` parameter like this:

`https://website.com/view?id=8d23iva/amazing-book-title`

I have been messing around changing the req and res object data before the user is sent to the page similarly to this.

```
app.get('/view', (req, res, next) => {
    res.baseUrl = "/test";
    req.url = req.url + '/test';
    req.originalUrl = req.originalUrl + '/test';

    next();
});
```

Comment: Please try [redirect](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect)

Answer (score 0):

As an HTTP server, the primary way you can influence the client (i.e the users browser) is with your HTTP response. To change their location you can return a redirection response.

A redirection response is any HTTP response with a 3XX status code and a `Location` header set to the new destination. In express you can use `res.redirect(/*your location here*/)` to send a redirection response. For more information about different types of redirects check out [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections).

As a side note, you could also consider making the change to the location using javascript on the client once the page is loaded. Though this will depend on other factors. You could investigate the [History api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) for this.